# How to check other containers file systems within a k8s pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Pod which contains two containers - *nginx* and *busybox*. Now I want to access the files within *nginx* container from the *busybox* container, say doing 'ls /etc/nginx' in *busybox* container to list the files there. Is there any configuration in k8s pod to allow me to achieve this?

Below is my current pod yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginxbusybox
  name: nginxbusybox
spec:
  shareProcessNamespace: true
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
  - image: busybox
    name: busybox
    command:
    - sleep
    - '86400'
```

P.S. This is for debugging a container which don't have the common linux tools within.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've found a way to achieve this. By using the 'kubectl debug' and checking the /proc/1/root/, I could see the filesystem in the nginx container. Below's what this looks like.

[image]

Comment: So with debug you can take your debug tools and run it with running pod.

Comment: Yes, you could change this debug container by specifying a new image --image=your_favoriate_debug_container_image and use whatever tools there.